# How to update UI from sqlite database according to current date?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a daily devotional reading application that i am working on. I have some data structured in my `sqLite` database for each day for a period of one year. I want to update the `UI` from my `database` according to each present day. I have already inserted my data in the database but i am stuck on how to update the `UI` according to current date. Please i need helpful ideas.

Comment: when starting app, do `Select` from your DB, and change UI according to your result.

Comment: how do i make sure the data is according to the user's date

Comment: By getting user's date from the device, and selecting the data based on the date

Answer (score 0):

You need to write select query with where class fetch record equal to today. Get the result cursor and read all fields and bind on UI.

In your case, the DB2 file is having static data. You can add this to project as part of assets folder but application can not considered it as secured db file. Please follow the link to copy the DB file from asset folder to application folder.
https://blog.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/